# FAQ for wiki privilege is incorrect on some sites

Tags: bug, status-declined, community-wiki, privileges

The FAQ section for the wiki edit privilege is wrong:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki

It says that it takes 30 posts to make a question automatically a community wiki.  It's 15, not 30.  I didn't know where else I was supposed to put this (it's not something that I can edit).

(This also effects superuser)

Comment: shipping this to meta.so so I can track it

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are editable, but only from the main http://meta.stackoverflow.com site. We then sync the information to the rest of the sites.

To fully fix this we are going to need to add a mechanism for extended config variable replacements before baking the markdown. So the markdown reads: `a question generates more that **$EditsTillWiki**` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

We've since adopted a new system based on help center which allows easy per-site customization. [Sam's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124155/131112) is therefore now obsolete.